# Batch script to get matching expression file name in a folder

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch

Using batch script, I go inside folder and in that folder, I've different files like -

```
ABc.txt
Pqr.png
.
.
Test-1.2.0.zip
```

Out of these file, I want to get name of a file which starts with `Test` and has extension `.zip`. In this case, `Test-1.2.0.zip`. As its version could be dynamic.

Could you please help me with the batch script to find `Test-1.2.0.zip` and return is as output?

Comment: In PowerShell you can just `gci Test*.zip` if you are in the correct dir, or `gci C:\somewhere Test*.zip` for a specific location

Comment: why do you list "powershell" in your tags? it looks like you want only BAT/CMD stuff ...

Comment: oh yeah I also thought this is PowerShell. Batch is the same though `dir Test*.zip`

Answer (score 1):

By click right on windows logo in start bar choose "run" from the list and opene it. Then write this word "recent" and click OK. It will be open a recent folder on your laptop try search in it about your file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `For /F` loop with:

`where .:Strings/Characters+Wildcard+String/Characters`

The `where` command assume `"."` as literal character, not Regex 1 Digit/Character:

```bat
1 Digit/character          <==>  ? 
1 or More Digit/Character  <==>  *
```

```bat
Test-  1 Digit/Character . 1 Digit/Character . 1 Digit/Character.zip        <==> Test-?.?.?.zip
Test-  1 Digit/Character . 1 Digit/Character . 1 or More Digit/Character:   <==> Test-?.?.*.zip
```

- Use `For /F` with `%%~nxi` (**N**ame e**X**Tension)

```bat
@echo off 

for /f useback^tokens^=* %%i in (`where .:"Test-?.?.?.zip"`)do echo\%%~nxi
```

- For Powershell:

```bat
Get-ChildItem -File '*.zip'| Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Test-?.?.?.zip'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name


# Or..
ls -af '*.zip'| ? {$_.Name -like 'Test-?.?.?.zip'} |select -Exp Name
```

- Results:

```bat
Test-1.2.0.zip
Test-1.2.1.zip
Test-1.2.2.zip
Test-1.2.3.zip
Test-1.2.4.zip
Test-1.2.5.zip
Test-1.2.6.zip
Test-1.2.7.zip
Test-1.2.8.zip
Test-1.2.9.zip
```

```bat
for /f useback^tokens^=* %%i in (`where .:"Test-?.?.*.zip"`)do echo\%%~nxi
```

- For Powershell:

```bat
Get-ChildItem -File '*.zip'| Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Test-?.?.*.zip'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name


# Or..
ls -af '*.zip'| ? {$_.Name -like 'Test-?.?.*.zip'} |select -Exp Name
```

- Results:

```bat
Test-1.2.0.zip
Test-1.2.1.zip
Test-1.2.10.zip
Test-1.2.11.zip
Test-1.2.12.zip
Test-1.2.13.zip
Test-1.2.14.zip
Test-1.2.15.zip
Test-1.2.16.zip
Test-1.2.17.zip
Test-1.2.18.zip
Test-1.2.19.zip
Test-1.2.2.zip
Test-1.2.20.zip
Test-1.2.3.zip
Test-1.2.4.zip
Test-1.2.5.zip
Test-1.2.6.zip
Test-1.2.7.zip
Test-1.2.8.zip
Test-1.2.9.zip
```

---

- For **R**everse **Sort** use `` for ... ^| Sort /r`) do ... `` in cmd/bat code, for PowerShell add `| Sort-Object -Descending`

```bat
for /f useback^tokens^=* %%i in (`where .:"Test-?.?.*.zip"^|sort /r`)do echo\%%~nxi
```

- For Powershell:

```bat
Get-ChildItem -File '*.zip'| Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Test-?.?.*.zip'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object -Descending


# Or..
ls -af '*.zip'| ? {$_.Name -like 'Test-?.?.*.zip'} |select -Exp Name | Sort -Des
```

- Results:

```bat
Test-1.2.9.zip
Test-1.2.8.zip
Test-1.2.7.zip
Test-1.2.6.zip
Test-1.2.5.zip
Test-1.2.4.zip
Test-1.2.3.zip
Test-1.2.20.zip
Test-1.2.2.zip
Test-1.2.19.zip
Test-1.2.18.zip
Test-1.2.17.zip
Test-1.2.16.zip
Test-1.2.15.zip
Test-1.2.14.zip
Test-1.2.13.zip
Test-1.2.12.zip
Test-1.2.11.zip
Test-1.2.10.zip
Test-1.2.1.zip
Test-1.2.0.zip
```

---

- Some further reading **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**

  - **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**
  - **[Where /ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**
  - **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
  - **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
  - **[Echo on | off | Strings](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

---

- Some further reading **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

  - **[Sort-Object | Sort](https://ss64.com/ps/sort-object.html)**
  - **[Select-Object | select](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)**
  - **[Where-Object | where | ?](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)**
  - **[Get-ChildItem | gci | ls](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)**

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /f useback^tokens^=* %%i in (`where .:"temp-?.?.*.tar.gz"`)do echo\%%~nxi
```

this solution worked for me in batch script

**?** represents 1 digit/character and **star(*)** char represents 1 or more digit/character